# What is "Mom's Letter" and should I sell it?

Tags: far-cry-4

In Far Cry 4 the game starts and my precious rucksack real estate is taken up with "Mom's Letter". Is there a reason to keep this or should I just sell it?

It's not that I need the money so much as the rucksack real estate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do anything, it is the character's mom last letter to him ( her death wish ). It doesn't matter if you sell it or keep it.

I don't want to spoil anything, but at the end of the game you will read it, so i suggest to keep it since it isnt worth almost anything anyway

Comment: Do I still read it if I don't have it?

Comment: Almost 100% sure yes

Comment: [Reddit post 1](http://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/2nadiu/what_does_moms_letter_do/)
[Reddit post 2](http://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/2nmy4t/moms_letter/)
These posts might help you as well

Answer (score 1):

You can read it before the end of the game (anytime, not just at the end of the game).

All you have to do is go to where you sell your items in your loot bag, and go to "Mom's Note" and it tells you what it says at the bottom left of the screen.